# What song plays at Naruto Shippuden episode 119 that sounds like Denkousekka?

Tags: naruto, music

In episode 119 of *Naruto Shippuden*, especially at 15:28, there's a song that sounds like "Lightning Speed" (*Denkousekka*) but with another instrument and another song playing over it.

What's that song?

Answer (score 1):

This is *Kouchaku* ("Stalemate") from *Shippuden* OST 1, track 21. The part at the timestamp you refer to appears about midway through the track.

For reference, another memorable scene where this track plays (or at the very least, a variant without drums) is during the Kakashi vs. Deidara fight (at 6:30 of *Shippuden* episode 29). Whenever I hear this track, I'm always reminded of that scene in particular.